# R programming simulation

Tags: r, simulation

I have been working on my simulation problem in R . The problem is

*A miner is trapped in a mine and he have 3 doors to choose from.

Door 1 = he can get out in the mine and will take 2hrs,

Door2 =  he will travel in 3hrs but only to return back in the mine,

Door3 = same situation as door 2 but 5hrs.*

I have already created a random number generator that will stop if it gets 1 ( using a while loop), but my problem is how to repeat this a 100 times and put the results in a table column. Are there any simplier solution in doing this kind of problem? (R beginner here)

Here is my code.:

```
library(purrr) 
storage <-c() 
d = NULL 
x1 <- rdunif(1, 3, a=1) 

while ( x1 != 1) { 
  x1<- rdunif(1, 3, a=1) 
  storage <-c(storage, x1) 
} 

storage
```

Comment: If my answer helps you, please upgrade it, thanks

Comment: sorry im new here in stack. but i already press the check button but the upvote says it will record but it will not display. did i did right? @Darren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- store 100 experiments in a list with 100 parts
- `n` means the number of door 1. If door 1 appears, enter the next experiment.
- `trial` means the order of experiments

---

```
storage <- vector("list", 100)
n <- 0
trial <- 1
while(n < 100){
    x <- sample(1:3, 1)
    storage[[trial]] <- c(storage[[trial]], x)
    if(x == 1){
        n <- n + 1
        trial <- trial + 1
    }
}

storage
```

Afterward, I suggest you not converting the list to dataframe because the length of every trial is different. It will generate many NA values with dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
hour <- lapply(storage, recode, `1` = 2, `2` = 3, `3` = 5)
total <- lapply(hour, sum) %>% unlist
```

`lapply` is a good tool to deal with list data.

Comment: thank you for this @Darren.  Now i have converted my list into columns for display using plyr. plyr::ldply(storage, rbind) . My next goal now is to convert each number to their corresponding hours and add.

Comment: @RodelG.Aldema I update my answer. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much for this @Darren.